# Get XML attribute and value from elements

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

I am being provided the following XML, with no ability to change the structure:

```
<ReportSpec>
  <Report ReportName="ReportName1" FilterMode="Container" Destination="EmailToUser:LoggedInUser" Format="PDF" AlertSource="ALL" CriticalStatus="True">
    <Filter Students="ALL" />
  </Report>
  <Report ReportName="ReportName1" FilterMode="Container" Destination="EmailToUserGroup:UserAdmins" Format="PDF" AlertSource="ALL" CriticalStatus="False">
    <Filter TestScore="1234" />
  </Report>
  <Report ReportName="ReportName1" FilterMode="Container" Destination="Dir:\\net.path.com\reports" Format="PDF" AlertSource="Failing">
    <Filter Grade="ALL" />
  </Report>
  <Report ReportName="ReportName1" FilterMode="Container" Destination="EmailTo:a@b.com,joe@schmoe.com" Format="PDF" AlertSource="Failing">
    <Filter Course="Programming" />
  </Report>
</ReportSpec>
```

I am using C# (.NET 4.5), and need to pick up the attribute name and value of the `<FILTER>` elements, as they will become part of the app logic later in code (that is, I want to collect `TestScore="1234"` as an entire string, and use it later on).  I am currently using `XMLSerializer` and `StreamReader` to load the XML document (but I am willing to change my approach, if need be).  I've done the `PASTE SPECIAL --> XML to Classes` in Visual Studio 2013, but the Filters class that gets created won't allow me to perform a `foreach` over the elements.  Can this be done, and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use XmlDocument class

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var file = File.ReadAllText("c:\\temp\\file.xml");
        var xmlFile = new XmlDocument();
        xmlFile.LoadXml(file);

        var filterElements = xmlFile.GetElementsByTagName("Filter");
        foreach (XmlNode filterNode in filterElements) {
            var filterName = filterNode.Attributes[0].Name;
            var filterText = filterNode.Attributes[0].InnerXml;
            var destination = filterNode.ParentNode.Attributes["Destination"].InnerText;
            var message = string.Format("the destination {0} will filter {1} by {2}", destination, filterName, filterText);
            Console.WriteLine(message);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

And the output will be:

*the destination EmailToUser:LoggedInUser will filter Students by ALL*

*the destination EmailToUserGroup:UserAdmins will filter TestScore by 1234*

*the destination Dir:\net.path.com\reports will filter Grade by ALL*

*the destination EmailTo:a@b.com,joe@schmoe.com will filter Course by Programming*

Comment: You could use XPATH to get the all of the Filter elements such as `xmlFile.SelectNodes("//Filter[@TestScore]")` would return all Filter elements with an Attribute of TestScore

Comment: Is there truly no way around hard-coding elements?  To me, hard-coding has always been a big no-no.

Answer (score 0):

Try xml linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XElement reportSpec = XElement.Load(FILENAME);

            var reports = reportSpec.Elements("Report").Where(x => x.Element("Filter").Attribute("TestScore") != null).FirstOrDefault();

            int score = (int)reports.Element("Filter").Attribute("TestScore");
        }
    }
}
```